# Exception handling for undeclared variable in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I want to write a exception if my program access the undeclared variable. Is it possible to do in C++ ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your program won't compile if you try to access the undeclared variable. Do you mean uninitialized variable? Then it will be undefined behavior.

Comment: exception handling is a runtime action, undeclared identifier is a compile-time error.

Comment: undeclated or uninitiated?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html